# Openoffice Calc - Quickly count marked lines when filter is active

Tags: openoffice-calc

I need help counting lines.

When I set a filter (AutoFilter) in Calc, rows that are filtered are hidden, but all rows keep their row number.

How can I see quickly, how many lines are currently visible / not filtered?

The best way I have right now is to mark the whole sheet and copy it into a new sheet and count the lines there by jumping to the end of the spreadsheet.

I'm looking a a quicker way to count the lines that doesn't require to change the document or to open extra sheets.

Answer (score 2):

Use [subtotal](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SUBTOTAL_function)

`subtotal(2;A#:A#)`

```
Syntax:
Subtotal(function; range)
range is which cells are selected by filtering for calculation. 
function is a number that specifies the function to calculate, as follows: 


function     Function 
   1         AVERAGE 
   2         COUNT 
   3         COUNTA 
   4         MAX 
   5         MIN 
   6         PRODUCT 
   7         STDEV 
   8         STDEVP 
   9         SUM 
   10        VAR 
   11        VARP
```

If you need help with the Function see [this documnetation](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_Functions_listed_by_category)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the function a bit more? What do the parameters mean?

Comment: Thanks, this works with the filter. Only question left is if there is a way to "run" this formula without entering it into a cell as this would change the document and is not permitted on write protected files.

Comment: Worked for me... 3 years and 6 months later. +1 ! ;)